# How to write to a fd replacing the original data of the same length?

Tags: c, posix

I have a file descriptor, now I want to write n bytes to that file replacing n bytes of original data (so the total file size won't change), like in replace mode of a word processor. Any convenient way to achieve this?

Comment: Look at `open` to open a file in read/write mode, `seek` to rewind the file pointer after reading, and the `read` and `write` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `write` to the fd. You might need to `read` up to the right position before or `lseek` or `lseek64` directly to the right position.

You must be sure that the fd is writable. You need to check `open` for that. `open` must have been called with `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR` but without `O_TRUNC` which would have truncated the file to zero length.

Note: `write` to a file only changes (increases) the file size if you are writing over the end of the file. If you are writing right into the file it's size does not change.